# ActiveMQ: adding users and console access

Tags: activemq-classic

With reference to the ActiveMQ security documentation at http://activemq.apache.org/security.html, I'm trying to add a new user to my ActiveMQ configuration. This user should only be able to see a subset of the available queues.

I have done the following:

1) Added an entry in users.properties:

```
myuser=mypassword
```

2) Added an entry in groups.properties:

```
publishers=admin,myuser
consumers=admin,myuser
```

3) Added an entry to activemq.xml, in the plugins element of the broker element:

```
<authorizationPlugin>
  <map>
    <authorizationMap>
      <authorizationEntries>
        <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
        <authorizationEntry queue="MYQUEUEPREFIX.>" read="consumers" write="publishers" admin="admins" />
      </authorizationEntries>
    </authorizationMap>
  </map>
</authorizationPlugin>
```

When I restart ActiveMQ and access the admin console at myServerURL:8161/admin, I enter the newly created username and password (myuser/mypassword) in the supplied "Authentication required" box but it doesn't give me access to the console. The only way I can get in is by using the already-defined "admin" user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between getting access to ActiveMQ queues via the broker and accessing the ActiveMQ web console. One has to modify the conf/jetty-realm.properties file in order to grant access to the latter.